# how to find 10-year return distribution from annual return distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, random

- Assume there is a $10$-year project whose annual return has normal distribution with parameters
  ${\rm N}\left(\mu,\sigma\right)$. $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are known.
- Now I wanna know what is the distribution of $10$-year return of this project $?$. I mean what is the type of $10$-year return distribution and its parameters $?$.
- e.g. in deterministic space if annual return is $15 \%$, $10$-year return will be $1.15^{10} - 1$

I think the answer is :$\mu_{new}\ =\ (1+\mu)^{10}-1$ and
$\sigma_{new}\ =\ \left(1 + \sigma\right)^{10} - 1$.

Am I right $?$. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is the annual return of a "project"? Is it reinvested somehow so that there is a compounding effect, or is it simply paid out (and possibly invested in other things)? If you are looking for a distribution of compounded earnings, things get complicated, because a $10\%$ return the first year and a $10\%$ loss the second year don't come out to zero return; they come out to **negative** return.